# Expression for $α/\bar α$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $α = a+b\sqrt{d} ∈ \mathbb Q[\sqrt{d}]$, how can I find an expression for $α/\bar α$ in terms of $a$, $b$, and $d$. And also for this problem, assume that $d$ is not a perfect square too.

Comment: [http://www.google.com/search?q=rationalize+denominator](http://www.google.com/search?q=rationalize+denominator)

Comment: @anon So what marwalix did was all I had to do?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @anon Wow I'm pretty dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of systematic approach multiply numerator and denominator by the conjugate of $\bar{\alpha}$ which is $\alpha$. So

$$\frac{\alpha}{\bar{\alpha}}=\frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha\bar{\alpha}}$$

And we have $\alpha^2=a^2+db^2+2ab\sqrt{d}$ and $\alpha\bar{\alpha}=a^2-db^2$